# how to verify mobile number into laravel5.4 using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I want to verify my mobile number using AJAX request into laravel but i am getting whole page into my input box fields form Ajax response.. it is loading all page content into my input box.  i written code into view page for send request

```
$( "#mobile" ).blur(function () {
        if($( "#mobile" ).val().length == 10)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('user/check_mobile')}}",
                type: 'get',
                data: {mobile:mobile.value},
                dataType:'html',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    $( "#mobile" ).val( data );
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

my controller page code

```
 public function check_mobile ( Request $request )
{
    $u = users::where('mobile',$request->input('mobile'))->exists();
    echo $u;  // return $u;
}
```

so after this whole page is loading into my mobile input field....

Comment: something to do with `dataType:'html'`

Comment: There is no html output in that method - are you sure that your routes actually point to that method? Are you sure the html isnt actually an error page or similar?